# Как прочитать строку с атрибутом? Xml

Tags: c#, xml

Есть допустим такой xml-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <UTF-8 />
  <string id="book">бла-бла</string>
  <string id="book_anatomy">бла-бла-бла</string>
  </data>
```

Как прочитать строку по атрибуту и получит с нее текст в C#?
Например, мне нужно получить текст "бла-бла" из строки id="book", как это сделать?

Comment: xpath в помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как это сделать. Используя **LINQ to XML** API.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\Temp\hex.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    
    string xelem = xdoc.Descendants("string")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value.Equals("book"))
        .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
        
    Console.WriteLine(xelem);
}
```

**Output**

```
бла-бла
```

Comment: `Where` тут лишний, раз ищется один объект. Всю лямбду в `FirstOrDefault` передаете, да и все. Также, не уверен как это работает в `XDocument`, но обычно, если делается `Attribute("id").Value`, то если атрибута нет, будет `NULL`, а взять из `NULL` значение = ошибка. Стоит это учесть и сделать, например `Attribute("id")?.Value`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ лучше `(string)Attribute("id")` (там операторы приведения типа определены)